# Generating coffee script in VS2012 use WebEssentials or Mindscape

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coffeescript

The coffee script code:

```
class ClassA
  constructor: ->
    alert ("Hello World")
```

Generating Javascript code use Web Essentials or Mindscape:

```
(function() {
  var ClassA;
  ClassA = (function() {
    function ClassA() {
      alert("Hello World");
    }
    return ClassA;
  })();
}).call(this);
```

But when I use http://js2coffee.org/ or http://coffeescript.org/ will be Generating:

```
var ClassA;
ClassA = (function() {
  function ClassA() {
    alert("Hello World");
  }
  return ClassA;
})();
```

Why a different?  How should I generating the second code in VS2012?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two versions is simply given by using or not using the top-level function safety wrapper. http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope

The default is to use it, so you get the result you see in Visual Studio.

http://js2coffee.org/ and http://coffeescript.org/ use the --bare option.

see http://coffeescript.org/#usage

Comment: If you're using Web Essentials, you can activate "bare" mode in VS 2013 with Tools->Options->Web Essentials->CoffeeScript->Wrap generated Javascript Files->False